# How to get root directory of windows using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, directory

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\windows\temp");
```

Here I want to replace c:\ with the current drive on which the user is operating windows.
Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SystemRoot")` and `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir")` should give you the path in form of "driveLetter:\\Windows"

So you can do:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SystemRoot"));
```

For the difference between "SystemRoot" and "windir" see:
https://superuser.com/questions/638321/what-is-difference-between-windir-and-systemroot

Answer (score 2):

In `.net` you ought to use `Path.GetTempPath` to get a temporary path:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.gettemppath?view=net-7.0&tabs=windows

Answer (score 0):

```
 DirectoryInfo di2 = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SystemRoot"));
            string path = Convert.ToString(di2);
            
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo( path + @"\temp");
```

I figured it out. Here is the corrected code.